# Конструктор копий неправильно копирует объект C++

Tags: c++

```
class vect
{
    int *vectors; 
    int l; //Количество 
     public:
    vect(int m);
    vect(const vect &obj);
    ~vect();
    int get_len(); //возвращает кол-во элементов
    void vect_adding(vect obj1, vect obj2);
};

vect::vect(int m) {
    l = m;
    vectors= new int [l];
} 

vect::vect(const vect &obj) //Конструктор копий (МНЕ КАЖЕТСЯ ТУТ Я ДЕЛАЮ ЧТО-ТО НЕ ТАК!!!!)
{
    vectors= new int; 
    *vectors= *obj.vectors;   //Копирую массив из obj
    l = obj.l;                //Копирую значение длины массива из obj
}

vect::~vect() {
     delete [] vectors;//Освобождаем память, которую выделили
}

int vect::get_len()
{
    return l;
}

void vect::vect_adding(vect obj1, vect obj2)
{
    int l1 = obj1.get_len(); 
    int l2 = obj2.get_len(); 
    l = l1;
    for (int i = 0; i < l;; i++)
    {
        int num1 = obj1.vectors[i];  //Тут когда i>0 он возвращает неправильное значение (какое-то длинное число 11232324)
        int num2 = obj2.vectors[i];
        //... остальной код
     }
     //... остальной код
}
```

В методе `vect_adding` переменные `num1` и `num2` при `i=0` получают правильное значение. Но в след. итерации когда `i=1` и больше, они получают какуюто ерунду(`12314134`). Кажется все дело в конструкторе копий. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3):

Да,  не так
Нужно в цикле присваивать каждое значение новому вектору
Нужно написать:

```
vect::vect(const vect &obj)
{
    vectors = new int[obj.l];
    l = obj.l;
    for(int i  = 0; i < obj.l; i++) {
        vectors[i] = obj.vectors[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы выделяете память только для одного элемента и копируете только первый элемент массива `obj.vectors` в выделенную память. Надо так:

```
vect::vect(const vect &obj) //Конструктор копий (МНЕ КАЖЕТСЯ ТУТ Я ДЕЛАЮ ЧТО-ТО НЕ ТАК!!!!)
{
    vectors = new int[obj.l]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < obj.l; i++) { //Копирую массив из obj
        vectors[i] = obj.vectors[i];
    }
    l = obj.l;                //Копирую значение длины массива из obj
}
```

Comment: я понял. Спасибо!